# Autocomplete php issue

Tags: php, pdo

I'm following a code posted in a website and it works well but i need to get the id and name and not only the name, everything is passed here

```
    $keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
 if ($keyword!= null) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM utilizador WHERE nome LIKE (:keyword) and estado = 1 ORDER BY idutilizador ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
    $query = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $rs) {
            $nome = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['nome']. ' ' .$rs['idutilizador']);
            $iduser = $rs['idutilizador'];
            echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['nome']).'\')">'.$nome.'</li>';
    }    
 }
```

The following line call's a function in javascript

```
echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['nome']).'\')">'.$nome.'</li>';
```

and i nedd to pass not only the $nome but also $iduser, how can i do it with that echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your javascript function receives 2 params you had to change

```
echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['nome']).'\')"data-lat="<?php echo $iduser; ?">'.$nome.'</li>';
```

to

```
echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['nome']).'\', \''.$userid.'\')" data-lat="<?php echo $iduser; ?">'.$nome.'</li>';
```